# Confused by the 'same day' wash same rule

Tags: united-states, wash-sale

Publication 550 states the following:

> Loss and gain on same day. Loss from a
> wash sale of one block of stock or securities
> cannot be used to reduce any gains on identical
> blocks sold the same day.
>
> Example. During 2016, you bought 100
> shares of X stock on each of three occasions.
> You paid $158 per share for the first block of
> 100 shares, $100 per share for the second
> block, and $95 per share for the third block. On
> December 27, 2021, you sold 300 shares of X
> stock for $125 per share. On January 10, 2022,
> you bought 250 shares of identical X stock. You
> cannot deduct the loss of $33 per share on the
> first block because within 30 days after the date
> of sale you bought 250 identical shares of X
> stock. In addition, you cannot reduce the gain
> realized on the sale of the second and third
> blocks of stock by this loss.

In this example, I'm assuming how this works is that the loss of $33 per share from the first lot of 100 shares is recaptured by increasing the basis of the 250 shares bought on January 10 by $3300.

However, what if I bought only 50 shares on January 10th? Does that mean I can only realize a loss of $1650? What happens to the remaining disallowed $1650 loss from the first wash sale?

Comment: From [Fairmark](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/same-day-rule/), a reputable tax web site: "Same Day Rule for Wash Sales - How the wash sale rule applies to same day sales.